# How I can match jalili calender with hijri calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I want to show jalali calendar and hijri calendar at the same time, but i don't know how to match jalali days with hijri days. I searched and found the source code below. It shows jalali calendar but I don't know how to match two calendars. Hijri calendar does'nt have any specific pattern for months.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class TestCal {
    /** Main method */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Prompt the user to enter year
    String yearString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

            "Lotfan Sale morede nazar ra vared konid (Masalan 1390):");



    // Convert string into integer
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);



    // Prompt the user to enter month
    String monthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

            "Lotfan mahe khod ra niz az miane adade 1 ta 12 bargozinid:");



    // Convert string into integer
    int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);



    // Print calendar for the month of the year
    printMonth(year, month);

}



/** Print the calendar for a month in a year */

static void printMonth(int year, int month) {

    // Print the headings of the calendar
    printMonthTitle(year, month);



    // Print the body of the calendar
    printMonthBody(year, month);

}



/** Print the month title, e.g., May, 1999 */

static void printMonthTitle(int year, int month) {

    System.out.println("         " + getMonthName(month)

            + " " + year);

    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");

}



/** Get the English name for the month */

public static String getMonthName(int month) {

    String monthName = null;

    switch (month) {

        case 1: monthName = "Farvardin"; break;

        case 2: monthName = "Ordibehesht"; break;

        case 3: monthName = "Khordad"; break;

        case 4: monthName = "Tir"; break;

        case 5: monthName = "Mordad"; break;

        case 6: monthName = "Shahrivar"; break;

        case 7: monthName = "Mehr"; break;

        case 8: monthName = "Aban"; break;

        case 9: monthName = "Azar"; break;

        case 10: monthName = "Dey"; break;

        case 11: monthName = "Bahman"; break;

        case 12: monthName = "Esfand";

    }



    return monthName;

}



/** Print month body */

public static void printMonthBody(int year, int month) {

    // Get start day of the week for the first date in the month
    int startDay = getStartDay(year, month);



    // Get number of days in the month
    int numberOfDaysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, month);



    // Pad space before the first day of the month
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < startDay; i++)

        System.out.print("    ");



    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++) {

        if (i < 10)

            System.out.print("   " + i);

        else

            System.out.print("  " + i);



        if ((i + startDay) % 7 == 0)

            System.out.println();

    }



    System.out.println();

}



/** Get the start day of the first day in a month */

public static int getStartDay(int year, int month) {

    // Get total number of days since 1/1/1800
    int startDay1300 = 1;

    int totalNumberOfDays = getTotalNumberOfDays(year, month);



    // Return the start day
    return (totalNumberOfDays + startDay1300) % 7;

}



/** Get the total number of days since Jan 1, 1800 */

static int getTotalNumberOfDays(int year, int month) {

    int total = 0;



    // Get the total days from 1800 to year - 1
    for (int i = 1300; i < year; i++)

        if (isLeapYear(i))

            total = total + 366;

        else

            total = total + 365;



    // Add days from Jan to the month prior to the calendar month
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++)

        total = total + getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, i);



    return total;

}



/** Get the number of days in a month */

public static int getNumberOfDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {

    if (month <= 6 && month > 0)

        return 31;



    else if (month < 12 && month > 6)

        return 30;



    if (month == 12) return isLeapYear(year) ? 30 : 29;



    return 0; // If month is incorrect
}



/** Determine if it is a leap year */

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {

    return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 3 && year % 100 != 0);

}


}
```

Comment: The leap year rule of your Jalali calendar is obviously very similar to gregorian and hence not correct. Of course, the months of Jalali (Persian) and Hijri calendar are not at all related to each other (Jalali is strictly solar following vernal equinox while Hijri is strictly lunar). You should also consider the fact that there are several variants of Hijri calendar (do you want Saudi-Arabia or something else?). Please give more details about what you want. The only common denominator between both calendars is just the count of days since some epoch (allows a mathematical transformation).

Comment: You could also use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (with ui-module) and embed two graphical JavaFX-calendars, one for Persian and one for Hijri in a user interface and then synchronize both calendars, see also the [javadoc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/ui/javafx/CalendarPicker.html)

Comment: I know the Jalali leap year is different from Hijri(Saudi-Arabia) and this code works fine for Persian calendar but like the calendar in this link http://www.time.ir/ I want to synch Jalali days and Hijri days at the same time because some holidays in Persian calendar are the Hijri holidays and I want to show them with different color in my program.

Comment: Actually we have the persian date AP-1396-06-06. The next years when your calendar implementation with the wrong leap year rule will fail are: 1407, 1408, 1411, 1412, 1415 etc. So your calendar would only work for the next 11 years not longer. See also the well-known [rule of Omar Khayyam](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/calendar/src/main/java/net/time4j/calendar/PersianAlgorithm.java#L203).

Comment: Yes you are right. In Hijri calendar in every 30 years(Hijri period) they have 11 leap year(355 days) and the rest are normal(344 day). I read an article about Hijri calendar and it says that there is a standard method for calculating Hijri calender. I think I must use those rule for calculating the Hijri days first and then synch them with my Persian calendar. It is a webpage that I mentioned https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C_%D9%87%D8%AC%D8%B1%DB%8C_%D9%82%D9%85%D8%B1%DB%8C

Comment: About Hijri calendar, the truth is much more complex. There are at least 8 different algorithmic variants (including that you have in mind). And worse, some countries like Saudi-Arabia use completely different leap year rules (umalqura calendar), see also the English version of the wikipedia-page (unfortunately I cannot read farsi).

Comment: Yes as you mentioned there are 8 or 9 different algorithm to calculate Hijri days and you are right Saudi-Ariabia's calendar is completely different from the others. I think if I define a variable which has a value between -2 to +2 I can handle the month days for every years. Just I must adjust this variable at the first day of year because every year is different from the previous and next ones.

Comment: If you are allowed to use external libraries why not use existing solutions like in my lib Time4J, see classes like `HijriCalendar`, `HijriAdjustment` (good for regional variants) etc. No need to reinvent the wheel. ;-) And `PersianCalendar` also exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use your lib Time4J in my project and sync two calendars with each other.Again thank you for your usefull comments.

Comment: In case of any questions or problems with realization, just put a new question with all necessary concrete details and time4j-tag here on SO, or open a question issue on the issue tracker of Time4J, and I will see how to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach:

1. Take a common epoch between two calendars
2. Develop/Find algorithms to convert calendar date to/from number of days between that epoch.
3. Convert date from calendar type A to epoch-delta and epoch-delta to calendar type B.

I have implemented a simple C library to convert between dates in various calendars. The code is available [here](https://github.com/soroush/libcalendars/). You can extract algorithms and implement them in your own language of choice. In case you are using C/C++, you can simply:

```
#include <calendars/cl-calendar.h>
int16_t year;
uint8_t month;
uint16_t day;
convert_date(CAL_ISLAMIC_CIVIL, CAL_SOLAR_HIJRI,
             1396, 7, 11, &year, &month, &day);
printf("1396/07/11 AP is: %d/%d/%d Hijri", year, month, day);
```

which will print:

```
$ 1396/07/11 AP is: 1439/1/12 Hijri
```

Notes:

- Jalali calendar is not being used anymore. You probably want to use Solar Hijri Calendar.
- Hijri Calendar is not tabular. You probably mean Islamic Civil Clanndar